# Serialization error when calling WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, datacontractserializer

When I call the service I receive this error:

> Element ListadoClientesResult from namespace tempuri.org cannot have child contents to be deserialized as an object. Please use XmlNode[] to deserialize this pattern of XML

The service code is:

```
public List<Empleado> ListarEmpleados()
{
    List<Empleado> returnList = new List<Empleado>();
    var lista = from u in DB.tabEmpleado
                select new
                {
                    u.idEmpleado,
                    u.idUsuario,
                    u.Nombre,
                    u.Apellidos,
                    u.Telefono1
                };                           
    foreach (var e in lista)
    {
        Empleado empleado = new Empleado();
        empleado.idEmpleado = e.idEmpleado;
        empleado.idUsuario = e.idUsuario;
        empleado.nombre = e.Nombre;
        empleado.apellidos = e.Apellidos;
        empleado.telefono1 = e.Telefono1;
        returnList.Add(empleado);                
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

And the class definition is this:

```
    [DataContract]
public class Empleado { 

private int _idEmpleado; 
[DataMember(IsRequired = false)] 
public int idEmpleado 
{ 
get { return _idEmpleado; } 
set { _idEmpleado = value; } 
}

private int _idUsuario;
[DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
public int idUsuario
{
    get { return _idUsuario; }
    set { _idUsuario = value; }
}

private string _nombre;
[DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
public string nombre
{
    get { return _nombre; }
    set { _nombre = value; }
}

private string _apellidos;
[DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
public string apellidos
{
    get { return _apellidos; }
    set { _apellidos = value; }
}

private string _telefono1;
[DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
public string telefono1
{
    get { return _telefono1; }
    set { _telefono1 = value; }
}
}
```

Here is the ServiceContract

```
   namespace MetodosNegocio
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<Empleado> ListadoClientes();
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we also see the ServiceContract?

Comment: Thank you for answering. ServiceContract added to the main message.

Comment: Can you please give us a full stack trace for the exception?

Comment: I am so sorry but it is working just after updating service references which were supossed to be outdated. How can I set it like solved?

Comment: Add an answer saying how you fixed it then accept that answer as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any change made in a service is not applied until you **update the service**, so I updated it and it was working.

Comment: I mean updating the service reference. Explained here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx